# Flask TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, flask, decimal, serializable

We are using flask for our application service. Internally we are using Jsonify to return the response and our response contains decimal data.

Couple of things to mention here.

1. We are using Windows machine
2. Some of my colleagues they are not getting any issue with the data with same configuration.
   One thing we observed is flask by default uses simplejson if installed. If not, then it will
   fall back to json package.

Sample data : jsonify({'response':Decimal('12345.00000')})

Our question is why for some people flask by default using simplejson and for others it's not able to identify simplejson(even though installed) and using only json throwing decimal json error.

Any idea what might be the root cause and what change needs to be done, let flask know to use simplejson over json ?

For time being we did below manual change in flask package.

[image: Manual Change to let flask take simplejson]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `jsonify({'response': Decimal('12345.00000')})` can't you just use `jsonify({'response': float('12345.00000')})`?

Comment: Hi Moritz... Yeah! That's a good idea, and we tried that too.

Application requires more precision. Moreover, we are looking to fix without code changes. When it's working in one system by taking simplejson why not in other system? What is that we are missing.

Answer (score 0):

is there any chance you're using different versions of flask?

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3555

in version 2, support was dropped for simplejson, but as noted in the comments, you can make it use simplejson for the JSONEncoder:

```
from simplejson import JSONEncoder

app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
```

it also looks as though there is a fix for the decimal issue that was PR'ed but is not yet released, and will be released in version 2.0.2